# Set up SMTP settings for orchard

Tags: asp.net, smtp, orchardcms

I'm trying to edit the SMTP setting for orchard
but every possible combination fails, meaning it just refreshes without any success.

I have tried using either gmail's or sendgrid's ones (https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/398734)
as various discussion on boards mention, but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any errors in the logs?

Comment: The latest version has testing ui in the settings screen that should give you information about why it fails.